# How to get matrix multiplication running using eigen and boost library?

Tags: c++, boost, eigen

I’d like to perform some calculations involving interval matrices. The code below shows my attempt using the C++ library eigen and the interval library of boost. I can fill a matrix with intervals, I also can add and also subtract these matrices, but I cannot multiply them, which is mandatory for me.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/interval/rounded_arith.hpp>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::interval_lib;
using namespace boost::numeric;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using Eigen::Matrix;

typedef interval<double, policies<save_state<rounded_transc_std<double> >,
checking_base<double> > > Interval;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    Matrix<double, 2, 2> a1;
    a1(0, 0) = 1;
    a1(0, 1) = 1;
    a1(1, 0) = 1;
    a1(1, 1) = 1;
    Matrix<double, 2, 2> b1;
    b1 = a1*a1; //this works

    //this works
    Interval c = Interval(2, 3) * Interval(-1, 4);

    Matrix<Interval, 2, 2> a;
    a(0, 0) = Interval(-1, 1);
    a(0, 1) = Interval(-2, 2);
    a(1, 0) = Interval(-3, 3);
    a(1, 1) = Interval(-4, 4);
    Matrix<Interval, 2, 2> b;
    b = a + a;  //this works
    b = a - a;  //this works
    b = a*a;    //this dose not complie

    return 0;
}
```

What is necessary to get the above code running? Or if it is easier how to perform interval matrix multiplication in C++?

edit: compiler error message included (sorry it is in german)

```
Fehler  1   error C2666: 'Eigen::RotationBase<Derived,3>::operator *': 3 Überladungen haben ähnliche Konvertierungen    39  1   eigen_test

2   IntelliSense: Mehr als ein "*"-Operator stimmt mit diesen Operanden überein:
        Funktionsvorlage "const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<Eigen::internal::promote_scalar_arg<Interval, T, Eigen::internal::has_ReturnType<Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<T, Interval, Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<T, Interval>>>::value>::type, Interval>, const Eigen::internal::plain_constant_type<Eigen::Matrix<Interval, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2>, Eigen::internal::promote_scalar_arg<Interval, T, Eigen::internal::has_ReturnType<Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<T, Interval, Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<T, Interval>>>::value>::type>::type, const Eigen::Matrix<Interval, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2>> Eigen::operator*(const T &scalar, const Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<Interval, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2>> &matrix)"
        Funktionsvorlage "const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<Interval, Eigen::internal::promote_scalar_arg<Interval, T, Eigen::internal::has_ReturnType<Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<Interval, T, Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<Interval, T>>>::value>::type>, const Eigen::Matrix<Interval, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2>, const Eigen::internal::plain_constant_type<Eigen::Matrix<Interval, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2>, Eigen::internal::promote_scalar_arg<Interval, T, Eigen::internal::has_ReturnType<Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<Interval, T, Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<Interval, T>>>::value>::type>::type> Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::operator*(const T &scalar) const [mit Derived=Eigen::Matrix<Interval, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2>]"
        Operandentypen sind: Eigen::Matrix<Interval, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2> * Eigen::Matrix<Interval, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2>    39  7   eigen_test
```

translation: error 1: 3 overloads have similar conversion

intelliSense: more than one “*”-operator matches with this operands

Comment: You should add the compiler error message.

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2015 (v141) and Eigen 3.2 your code compiles without errors or warnings for me.

Comment: @lakeweb, yes it does work with Eigen 3.2 but not with 3.3 because the logic for operator* between scalars and matrices has been changed to be more flexible regarding mixing types and type promotion. Unfortunately, boost `internal<>` has some design issue making `std::is_convertible<X,interval<>>` returning true for any X...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `interval<>` has a generic implicit constructor accepting anything. Therefore, we have:

```
is_convertible<Matrix<Interval,2,2>, Interval>::value == true
```

and the compiler is confused because `Matrix<Interval,2,2> * Matrix<Interval,2,2>` could also be a scalar times matrix product after converting one of the operands to an `Interval`.

You could workaround by specializing `Eigen::internal::is_convertible<X,interval<S>` to your needs, for instance:

```
namespace Eigen {
  namespace internal {
    template<typename X, typename S, typename P>
    struct is_convertible<X,interval<S,P> > {
      enum { value = is_convertible<X,S>::value };
    };

    template<typename S, typename P1, typename P2>
    struct is_convertible<interval<S,P1>,interval<S,P2> > {
      enum { value = true };
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I’ll be honest, i don’t fully understand your answer but this solves my problem. Thank you very much. :)